# when getActivity() can return null?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Maybe silly question but when `getActivity()` can retun null and is it OK to save `getActivity()` to field in `onViewCreated` for examle to `mActivity` and use it everywhere?

First example, method onStop in fragment. Is it OK or I should never check like that?:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    registrationMessage(RequestService.MSG_UNREGISTER);
    if (getActivity() != null)
        getActivity().unbindService(serviceConnection);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensuring the context is not null in onStop is fine,
Here is the caution line from the [developers documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) -

> if you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call
>   getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only when the
>   fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not yet
>   attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle,
>   getActivity() will return null.